# Can a tautology be proven directly from a single premise?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have the following:

1. P :. Q v ~Q

Can this be proven without making assumptions for conditional or indirect proofs? (The rules of inference are the one's found in Copi's book, given here: https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2012/rulesLogic.html )

Perhaps I just lack ingenuity but I see no way of doing so.

Comment: Are you interested in this particular case or how this can be done in general ? I am not sure whether only applying the rules will always work. Considering SAT , which is NP-complete , I doubt that we usually have anything better than checking all cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what SAT stands for. But usually I would just do an indirect proof, but I have been asked if a direct proof can be given, and I'm stumped.

Comment: A proof of a logic formula needs a proof system, like e.g. Natural Deduction. A tautology is proved in ND with a derivation **without** undischarged assumption; but this does not mean that you have no assumptions used in the derivation: they will be discharged using Conditional Proof.

Comment: Well, I was able to find a proof without assumptions to my suprise.

Comment: Determining whether some statement is a tautology is equivalent to determine whether the negation is not satisfyable. This is an NP-complete problem, so probably not feasible efficiently in general.

Comment: I mention that because you apparently disagreed to the brute force method, but we do not always have something better. In this particular case, there might be another possibility. Moreover, the brute force method is not indirect.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348010/proving-c-vdash-d-lor-neg-d-using-natural-deduction-and-without-any-additi

Comment: @Bram28 I'm glad I'm not the only one that thought this wasn't an easy proof! I rarely use a 100% direct approach as it certainly isn't always "natural".

Comment: @Casey Hey, you found it. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

1. G
2. ~H v G (1 Add)
3. H --> G (2 Material Implication)
4. H --> (H & G) (3 Absorption)
5. ~H v (H & G) (4 Material Implication)
6. (~H v H) & (~H v G) (5 Distribution)
7. ~H v H (6 Simplification)
8. H v ~H (7 Commutation)

Answer (score 0):

If we use the truth table, we check easily that your argument is valid since the conclusion is always true whatever the logical value of the premisse.

Comment: Nothing to add (+1)

Comment: @Peter Thanks Peter, God bless you from Coro..

Comment: I know it's a valid argument. I'm wondering if the tautology is provable from 19 inference rules without conditional or indirect proof, as I've tried to find a proof but couldn't.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah  Unfortunately, I do not believe in a god, but nevertheless thanks for your wish that I stay healthy.

Comment: By definition of the disjunction and the negation, $ q\vee \lnot q$ is Always true. You don't need any premisse.